# Seleccionar pseudo-elemento con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo esta pseudoclase:

```
.swiper-pagination-v::after{
    content: "\25b6";
    margin: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Y necesito seleccionarla porque es la flecha que hace que el slider funcione, para ello está esta clase de javascript:

```
swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination-h',
            paginationClickable: true,
            direction: 'vertical',
            spaceBetween: 50,
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next-v',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev-v',
```

donde `nextButton` es la pseudoclase, y la cosa es que no encuentro nada de nada.

Lo he intentado con muchos selectores, atributos y nada, a ver si me podéis ayudar por favor. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: puedes agregar la librerias que utilizas?

Answer (score 1):

No se si te entiendo lo que quieres decir pero hasta donde yo sé, no puedes detectar un clic en un pseudoelemento como `:after` o `:before` porque no "existen" como tal en el DOM. 
Seria como intentar detectar un clic en un borde de color, para entendernos. 
En vez de usar content y :after, usa backgrounds en el div y detectalo directamente desde el div.

Comment: Si, me refiero a eso. No se puede clickear entonces?

Comment: Ciertamente, no es posible crear un evento de click sobre un seudoelemento porque no están en el DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que la clase a la cual necesitas darle click es esta **.swiper-button-next-v**, pero veo que en la API que estás usando te refieres a una propiedad **nextButton** y **prevButton** donde en la actual API no existe, me imagino que por eso quizás no te funciona, quizás estas usando la librería con la nueva API y tratando de usar un script de configuración con un método viejo, en la actual API para acceder a las flechas o botones de navegación seria lo siguiente:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next-v',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev-v',
  },
});
```

y para capturar el evento cuando el slider esta cambiando puedes usar:

```
mySwiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  console.log('slide changed');
});
```